# RDS Aurora Serverless V2 - Master User Account only gets Usage Privilege why ? even re-creating its Usage only

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, serverless, amazon-aurora

I created RDS serverless DB-instance, when I create the DB, I created the DB with the master username = root and some password, However, when I checked the user accounts, I can see that the root user is not actually a Superuser but a Normal user with minimum privileges of USAGE only.

This makes it impossible to create new users or manage the database servers as I don't have access to the server with the required privileges. Even going to modify the cluster and reset the password didn't work as it just keep on giving the root user as USAGE only, even deleting and re-creation didn't work,

**any ideas? see below**

[image]

Comment: Im facing the same issue, have you found a work around?

Comment: @DarraghBlake no real work around, it's by policy they don't allow it,